# How do I set the mysql workbench preferences permanently forever

Tags: mysql-workbench

I set the SQL editor DBMS connection read timeout interval to 0 so many times that there just has to be a way to save it so its the default option when I open MySQL Workbench.

[image]

Comment: Where did you set the connection timeout in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: You should consider removing the question about dbbeaver, which is indeed not appropriate for SO. Let's just focus on the connection read timeout problem in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Have you try closing WB after setting that value and reopen it? Maybe it wasn't stored before? The settings should be saved as soon as you close the preferences dialog, however.